# Probability notation?

Tags: probability, notation

I've tried to gather information about these three topics i'm about to show but i couldn't find. I will display them in a question for better understanding and context of the situation.

> For a and b real numbers, define:
>
> $a∨b := max ${a, b} and $a∧b := min${a,b}
>
> Let X and Y be such that $E(X∨Y) = 20$, and E(X∧Y) = 10. Get E|X-Y|.

**SO**, what's the ∨, ∧ and := symbols meaning that appear throughout the problem? If anyone could solve for better understanding and briefly talk about the min max part i'd appreciate.

Comment: They are used as as shorthand as defined for max and min.  Perhaps these hints will help to solve the problem  $$\max\{a,b\}=\frac12(a+b+|a-b|)$$
$$ E\{a+b\} = E\{a\}+E\{b\} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is occurring here is that the author is defining a notation, which is what the := sign is telling you.  In other words, the up carrot is a relation between two numbers that returns after operation the number which is smaller of $a$ and $b$.  Similarly the down carrot is a relation between two numbers that returns the number which is larger of $a$ and $b$.

So if we let $a=2, b=3$, then $2 \lor 3 = \max{\{2,3\}}=3$.  And $2 \land 3 = \min{\{2,3\}}=2$

I can honestly say that I've never seen that notation myself during my probability studies.  But I suppose since the author is defining it in his own way, using := to tell us so, then I suppose that is how the author wants his students to learn it.   I've always seen a new random variable defined just as say, let $Z=\max{\{X,Y\}}$ for r.v's $X,Y$.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was perfect Christopher!!!

Comment: It is quite a standard notation in probability, it is very common when dealing with stopping times for examples

Answer (score -1):

Note $$|X-Y| = \max\{X,Y\} - \min\{X,Y\}$$ and then take expectations and substitute.